# Load and fill templates with jQuery

Tags: jquery, templates

I have a website with changing content. I would like to load a template for a list of elements. The data for the elements are gathered by an ajax call independently.
My template is standard html. I would like to be able to load the template only once into js-memory and reuse it for all elements repeating it and appending it to my list with $(..).append(my new list-elemnt).

I figured how to load a file with .load() but I didn't manage to reuse and fill data into the template. Converting it into an jQuery-Object is one of my problems. Also I don't know what the best practice for this is.

To sum up, I would like to:
1. load a template (text/html) from server once
2. reuse it many times to fill data from a independently gatherd list
3. append it to an existing element in the DOM with $(my element).append()

Any ther standard jQuery-ways or better solutions are highly welcome. I would like to avoid adding another library/dependency for this thow.

Examples as jsfiddles are highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was:

1. marking fields in my template with data-properties
2. loading the template and clone it with [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
3. wrote a function that uses a JSON-response including the data-property-name and values to set by doing a foreach with keys and values where key is the value for the jQuery-selector as with:

```
$('*[data-name='+myKey+']').val(myValue);
```

Comment: Can you put your js function here? The problem I see here is that $('*[data-name='+myKey+']') selector should select already existing objects as well

Answer (score 1):

1. You could obtain a HTML file with a get request and parse it to a
   DOM element. This DOM element can be used as a template for custom data.
2. The DOM 'Template' can be modified with Jquery [traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and
   [manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) methods. In my example you can see I used the [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get an element by it's data attribute. Then I modified the text with the [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method.
3. And lastly you append the DOM template to my main HTML page.

template.html

```
<div class="card">
   <h1 data-name="firstName"></h1>
   <h2 data-name="lastName"></h2>
   <p data-name="profession"></p>
</div>
```

load-dynamic-data.js

```
let users = [
  {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Foome',
    age: 55
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Foome',
    age: 55
  }
];

$.get('html/template.html', function(data) {
    users.forEach(element => {
        let template = $.parseHTML(data);
        for (const key in element) {
            $(Template)
                .find('[data-name=' + key + ']')
                .text(element[key]);
        }
        $('div#content').append(template);
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Comment: I customized it, I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template id="template">
<p><a class="a_card_tit"</a></p>
</template>

<div id="titles"></div>


<script>
function fillTitleTemplate(title){
  template = $('#template');
  var node = template.prop('content');
  var name = $(node).find('.a_card_tit');
  name.text(title);
  $('#titles').append(template.html());
}
</script>
```

Where you can receive title from a POST call